# Running shell commands inside curl call in php

Tags: php, shell, curl, chmod

I am using curl as like below.
http://99.88.77.121/sample/curl.php

```
$ch = curl_init();
        $ip = "Some IP address";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://99.88.77.121/test/index.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        $payload = json_encode(
                            array( 
                                'username' => 'abc', 
                                'password' => '1234'
                                )
                            );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$payload);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec ($ch);
```

The above code sends the data to the Url.

I have code like below in my **http://99.88.77.121/test/index.php**

```
<?php 

  $fp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
  $rawData = stream_get_contents($fp);
  $data = json_decode($rawData);
  $username = $data->username;
  $password = $data->password;
  $projectName = "testFolder";
  chdir('../');
  //chdir($projectName);
  $command = "sudo chmod -R 777 ".$projectName;
  shell_exec($command);

?>
```

I am trying give full permission for testFolder using above code,

is chdir() and shel_exec() will work here? In my case its not working

If i run the index.php in browser, its working fine. but not from the curl call.

Can anyone look into it and update me your thoughts please.

Comment: why don't you use `chmod` function?

Comment: Not answerable without guessing the error message. Look into the linked references to investigate.

Comment: @mario, what need to guess, did you understand my question? my question is completely different

Comment: Yes, I think I did. No trace of error_reporting/debugging in your sample code though.

Comment: @mario, what info you need? have you got my question,? please read clearly then mark it as duplicate

Comment: Imagine you are asking this question over the internet, and people do *not* have access to your setup. Then look and read through the duplicates to **narrow "not working" down** to something concrete, in particular either the curl call, or the shell_exec wrapper.

Comment: @mario, did you get what is my question, i am using curl